# ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople Not returning any People

Tags: ios, xcode, abaddressbook

I am starting to work with the ABAddress Book and using a very simple starting point... I want to get all  the entries in my address book and put it into an array. It keeps showing 0 elements.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

Doesn't the `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` actually get all people from your contact list or did I misunderstand something.

**NOTE TO ADMIN's**  My question was a Objective C related and not for SWIFT so this answer doesn't apply. In the recommended answer it explains why the OP's code migration from Objective C to Swift is flawed and doesn't work. My question is not. I am trying to understand why when I install this on my iPhone, which has hundreds of contacts `allContacts` has no items. I was trying to understand the correct way to put all my contacts into an array. Basically because of business need I am doing my own contact picker because I don't want to use Apple's built in one.

Comment: Not a dupe . See my question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are trying to use deprecated apis. This may be why [ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/) doesn't work.

However, my recommendation based on your edit (where you say that you want to build your own UI) is to use the [Contacts framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html).

See [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/willthink/024f1394474e70904728):

```
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h>

@implementation ContactsScan

- (void) contactScan
{
    if ([CNContactStore class]) {
        //ios9 or later
        CNEntityType entityType = CNEntityTypeContacts;
        if( [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:entityType] == CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
         {
             CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
             [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:entityType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                 if(granted){
                     [self getAllContact];
                 }
             }];
         }
        else if( [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:entityType]== CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
        {
            [self getAllContact];
        }
    }
}

-(void)getAllContact
{
    if([CNContactStore class])
    {
        //iOS 9 or later
        NSError* contactError;
        CNContactStore* addressBook = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];
        [addressBook containersMatchingPredicate:[CNContainer predicateForContainersWithIdentifiers: @[addressBook.defaultContainerIdentifier]] error:&contactError];
        NSArray * keysToFetch =@[CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPostalAddressesKey];
        CNContactFetchRequest * request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc]initWithKeysToFetch:keysToFetch];
        BOOL success = [addressBook enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&contactError usingBlock:^(CNContact * __nonnull contact, BOOL * __nonnull stop){
            [self parseContactWithContact:contact];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)parseContactWithContact :(CNContact* )contact
{
    NSString * firstName =  contact.givenName;
    NSString * lastName =  contact.familyName;
    NSString * phone = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"];
    NSString * email = [contact.emailAddresses valueForKey:@"value"];
    NSArray * addrArr = [self parseAddressWithContac:contact];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)parseAddressWithContac: (CNContact *)contact
{
    NSMutableArray * addrArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    CNPostalAddressFormatter * formatter = [[CNPostalAddressFormatter alloc]init];
    NSArray * addresses = (NSArray*)[contact.postalAddresses valueForKey:@"value"];
    if (addresses.count > 0) {
        for (CNPostalAddress* address in addresses) {
            [addrArr addObject:[formatter stringFromPostalAddress:address]];
        }
    }
    return addrArr;
}

@end
```

Note: This code was not written by me. The source can be found on [github](https://gist.github.com/willthink/024f1394474e70904728).

Comment: Thank you sir! I saw the documentation on this and it said it was deprecated in 9.0. I had mine below 9 so I figured it should have worked.